# Spring MVC and MongoDB: Unit test with Fongo - returns Null Pointer Exception

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-mvc, nullpointerexception

I'm working on a *Spring*, *Spring MVC* and *MongoDB* backed application.

I'm looking add an integration test for saving and reading a document file with *Fongo*.

My test fixture class is the following:

```
@ActiveProfiles({ "test"})
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {SpringMongoConfig.class, MockDatasourceConfig.class})
@WebAppConfiguration
public class FSIntegrationFongoTest extends SpringApplicationContextTest {

  private MockMvc mockMvc;

  @Mock
  private FileService fileService;

  @Mock
  private FileStoreRequest file ;

  @Before
  @Test
  public void setUp() throws IOException {
    //set up FongoDB and collection
    Fongo fongo = new Fongo("FongoTest");
    DB db = fongo.getDB("dbtest");
    DBCollection collection = db.getCollection("filedocuments");

    //test database
    assertNotNull(db);
    assertSame("getDB should be idempotent", db, fongo.getDB("dbtest"));
    assertEquals(Arrays.asList(db), fongo.getUsedDatabases());
    assertEquals(Arrays.asList("dbtest"), fongo.getDatabaseNames());

    //test collection
    assertNotNull(collection);
    assertSame("getCollection should be idempotent", collection, db.getCollection("filedocuments"));

    //import json with collection name filedocuments
    importJSON("filedocuments", "src/test/resources/SampleFiles.json");

    fileService = Mockito.mock(FileServiceImpl.class);
    file = Mockito.mock(FileStoreRequest.class);
  }

  @Test
  public void testInsertFileAndGetIt()throws IOException{
    FileStoreRequest file = new FileStoreRequest();
    file.setId("test1");
    file.setFileName("test1");
    file.setVersionId("1");
    file.setDescription("Test file");
    file.setAlias("Testing");
    file.setContent(MockUtils.getMockFileContent());
    Map<String,String> extraAttributes = new HashMap<>();
    extraAttributes.put("parameter1", "parameter1Name");
    extraAttributes.put("parameter2", "parameter2Name");
    file.setExtraAttributes(extraAttributes);
    fileService.storeFileGeneral(file);
    System.out.println(file);
    assertNotNull(file);
    assertEquals("test1", file.getId());
    assertEquals("test1", file.getFileName());
    //this causes java.lang.NullPointerException
    assertEquals(fileService.getFileById("test1").getFileName(),  file.getFileName());
  }
}
```

Here down my `SpringApplicationContextTest` class:

```
@ActiveProfiles({ "test"})
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(classes = {SpringMongoConfig.class, MockDatasourceConfig.class,})
public class SpringApplicationContextTest {

  Logger log = LoggerFactory.getLogger(SpringApplicationContextTest.class);

  @Autowired
  private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

  public void importJSON(String collection, String file) {
    try {
      for (Object line : FileUtils.readLines(new File(file), "utf8")) {
        log.debug("Import Object to database:" + line);
        mongoTemplate.save(line, collection);
      }
    } catch (IOException e) {
      throw new RuntimeException("Could not import file: " + file, e);
    }
  }

  @Test
  public void testContextInitialized() {
    assertNotNull(mongoTemplate);
  }                                                                                                                     
}
```

Here down the project *pom.xml* file:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">

    <properties>
        <spring.version>4.3.3.RELEASE</spring.version>
        <hibernate.version>4.1.0.Final</hibernate.version>
        <spring.data.version>1.9.0.RELEASE</spring.data.version>
        <spring.mongodb.version>1.9.5.RELEASE</spring.mongodb.version>
        <apache.commons.io.version>2.5</apache.commons.io.version>
        <apache.commons.codec.version>1.10</apache.commons.codec.version>
        <apache.commons.fileupload>1.3.2</apache.commons.fileupload>
        <tika.version>1.14</tika.version>
        <swagger.version>2.6.1</swagger.version>
        <jstl.version>1.2</jstl.version>
        <javax.servlet.version>3.1.0</javax.servlet.version>
        <junit.version>4.12</junit.version>
        <hamcrest.version>1.3</hamcrest.version>
        <servlet.api.version>2.5</servlet.api.version>
        <mockito.version>2.2.15</mockito.version>
        <mockwebserver.version>3.8.0</mockwebserver.version>
        <jcl.slf4j.version>1.6.0</jcl.slf4j.version>
        <maven.compiler.source>1.7</maven.compiler.source>
        <maven.compiler.target>1.7</maven.compiler.target>
        <retrofit.version>2.3.0</retrofit.version>
        <okhttp.version>3.8.1</okhttp.version>
        <slf4jVersion>1.6.1</slf4jVersion>
        <nosqlunit-version>0.7.6</nosqlunit-version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- Spring framework -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-core</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
                    <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-beans</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-context</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- mongodb java driver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring data mongodb -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-mongodb</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.mongodb.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>cglib</groupId>
            <artifactId>cglib</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Spring controllers -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Apache commons -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-codec</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-codec</artifactId>
            <version>${apache.commons.codec.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>${apache.commons.io.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>${apache.commons.fileupload}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Apache tika -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tika</groupId>
            <artifactId>tika-core</artifactId>
            <version>${tika.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Swagger 2.0  -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>${swagger.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>${swagger.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Servlet , JSP, JSTL -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
            <version>${jstl.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- for compile only, your container should have this -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>${servlet.api.version}</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Testing Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <version>${junit.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
            <artifactId>hamcrest-library</artifactId>
            <version>${hamcrest.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
            <version>${javax.servlet.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
            <version>${mockito.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
            <artifactId>mockwebserver</artifactId>
            <version>${mockwebserver.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.jayway.jsonpath</groupId>
            <artifactId>json-path-assert</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.0</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.hamcrest</groupId>
                    <artifactId>hamcrest-core</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.github.fakemongo</groupId>
            <artifactId>fongo</artifactId>
            <version>1.6.8</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.lordofthejars</groupId>
            <artifactId>nosqlunit-mongodb</artifactId>
            <version>${nosqlunit-version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <!--  Jackson Dependencies -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.3</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-annotations</artifactId>
            <version>2.6.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <!--   Retrofit2  -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.squareup.retrofit2</groupId>
            <artifactId>retrofit</artifactId>
            <version>${retrofit.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.squareup.retrofit2</groupId>
            <artifactId>converter-gson</artifactId>
            <version>${retrofit.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.squareup.retrofit2</groupId>
            <artifactId>converter-jackson</artifactId>
            <version>RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.squareup.okhttp3</groupId>
            <artifactId>okhttp</artifactId>
            <version>${okhttp.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.httpcomponents</groupId>
            <artifactId>httpasyncclient</artifactId>
            <version>4.1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.google.code.gson</groupId>
            <artifactId>gson</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Bridge logging from JCL to SLF4j-->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>jcl-over-slf4j</artifactId>
            <version>${jcl.slf4j.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- Binding for NOP, silently discarding all logging. -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-nop</artifactId>
            <version>${slf4jVersion}</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>

</project>
```

I get a `NullPointerException` when running my test fixture:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.myproject.fongodb.FSIntegrationFongoTest.testInsertFileAndGetIt(FSIntegrationFongoTest.java:97)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:26)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestMethodCallbacks.java:75)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestMethodCallbacks.java:86)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.SpringRepeat.evaluate(SpringRepeat.java:84)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:252)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:94)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:70)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:51)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

Any clue on what is going wrong?

Comment: Could you add your project dependencies description please?

Comment: Thank for your direct response,i have added my pom.xml file

Comment: Could you please check which line is the 97th one within your `FSIntegrationFongoTest` class?
Seems like the `FileService` instance is not being injected.

Comment: The 97th line is the last one: assertEquals(fileService.getFileById("test1").getFileName(),  file.getFileName()), which causes the NullPointerException!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your test fixture `setUp` hook, you are initializing the `fileService` with a mock object:

```
fileService = Mockito.mock(FileServiceImpl.class);
```

Then you are trying to save your file using the mocked object:

```
fileService.storeFileGeneral(file);
```

Since the `fileService` is nothing but a mock, it will do nothing on `#storeFileGeneral` call and no file will be saved as you are expecting.

Later on, you are trying to read back the persisted file to asset that it has been created using the right id, while all you get is a `null` reference:

```
assertEquals(fileService.getFileById("test1").getFileName(),  file.getFileName()); // fileService.getFileById("test1") will return 'null'
```

The short answer would be to review your test fixture since it does not reflect an integration-test since you are testing your `FileService` behavior.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer,you are too helpful. However, i tried also to recreate this test without using Mocks and the result which i received was the same.I suppose that i haven't understood too well the integration testing with MongoDB.

Comment: Because i'm a new one (as i have mentioned later), where can i post my new trial? It is too long for comment.Thank you.

Comment: You are welcome.
To avoid highjacking the post, try to create another one with further details but keep attention to learn better on integration test & unit test since what you are trying to achieve in your test fixture is a unit (behavioral) test and does not interact with the backend db not even with a fake one as it should be the case with *fongo*.